# Web query with Power BI desktop returns empty table

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to import data from a web page to Power BI Desktop. The URL is the following:

```
https://casa.sapo.pt/Venda/Apartamentos/Maia/?sa=13
```

It contains data about housing prices, characteristics, etc.

The query returns an empty table, although if I browse to the page with any browser and without authentication or login, I see it contains the data I'm looking to analyse so I guess the publisher has disabled somehow the query I'm trying to make.

Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Power BI / Power Query gives quite disappointing results against that fairly typical page structure.  It only seems to work well against "Web 1.0" style HTML tables.  There are so few of those around (outside of Wikipedia) that it is almost pointless ...

You could try Chris Webb's ExpandAll function (link below) that will expand out all the data available.

http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/05/21/expanding-all-columns-in-a-table-in-power-query/

Then you can exclude all the non ".Text" columns and merge them together to get all the text from the page in one column - but it's hard to make sense of it.  You also lose a lot of the HTML content eg links, image URLs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll try to fetch the data using Google Sheet's IMPORTXML and from there to Power BI. Hopefully, Power BI will catch up in the future...

Comment: @NunoNogueira - that's interesting.  I tried but I couldn't get the syntax working.  Could you share what you used for IMPORTXML?

Comment: Have you tried: `=IMPORTXML("https://casa.sapo.pt/Venda/Apartamentos/Maia/?sa=13"
,ʺ//div[@class='searchResultProperty']ʺ)`

Comment: Yes, I tried different things, but Xpath is complicated for me, you may have a look here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12qUTv0uwfIZdFxdV5mrqTCxmVqoZkx68PPZvc5_FmiM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Any technology with a name starting with X is best avoided IMO - the people who named it are subtly trying to warn us all away ...

Comment: If the PBI ExpandAll function exposes the data you are after, you are probably better off down that path.  Add an Index column and think about Grouping and Counting rows, and Queries referring to other Queries.